# Mingw64 multiple definitions

Tags: c, multiple-definition-error, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile a quit big c-project with mingw64 on a windows 7 x64 machine using the codeblocks ide. I did the setup for the compiler according to this tutorial:
http://blog.marc-o.org/2010/mingw64-unter-windows-mit-codeblocks

Now I get multiple definitions errors of all kind of standard functions. See here:

```
multiple definition of `_Exit'|
multiple definition of `llabs'|
multiple definition of `atoll'|
multiple definition of `sinhf'|
multiple definition of `coshf'|
multiple definition of `tanhf'|
```

and so on. Does anyone has a clue what I am missing?

P.S.: The mingw32 version compiles just fine.

Comment: I assume error prompt might also contain the locations of definition. ??? i.e. Linker doesn't know which one to choose, isn't it?